# getting only one data from laravel collection seems difficult

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I don't get this, I have a collection of items.
The collection contains in this case one and only one item at index 1 as it was filtered from a bigger collection.
The point is how do I get the only piece of data I need without having to reset the values of the index and then accessing at index 0 ??
This is a case where I will always have only ONE item in the collection but the index at could be different so I can't use the [0] index by default.

```
//returns all items with 'item_color_id" = 1

$item = Item::where(//some constraints);

$filtered = $item->filter(function ($i) {
                return $i->item_color_id == 1;
            });

if (count($filtered)) {

    //need to access a single data inside the collection
    // like for example 'item_brand_id'
    //I can do it like this:

    $filtered = $filtered->values();

    $item_brand_id = $filtered[0]['item_brand_id'];

    //but what sense does it have?? how can we access 'item_brand_id'
    //from $filtered without resetting the indexes?

}
```

it doesn't make any sense to me that we don't have a method to access the data directly, or if we have it I missed it.
For example I coould use max() or min() on $filtered like this:

```
$max_brand_id = $filtered->max('item_brand_id');
```

It doesn't make any sense to find the max id in this case I know, but it shows that we can find the data in one passage.
I tried `only('item_brand_id);` but that returns empty while the data is there.

Comment: And where does the collection `$item` with one item come from?

Comment: that's another collection, what difference does it make in order to access the data from the filtered one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have `eloquent collection` so you can do just call first() function

```
$item_brand_id = $filtered->first()->item_brand_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` is used when you want a collection of matching elements, even if that only results in one element.

If you know that you only want one element that matches a truth test, use `first()` instead. It has the same signature.

```
Item::where(...)->get()->first(function ($item) {
    return $item->item_color_id == 1;
})->get('item_brand_id');
```

Comment: No because I don't want to use 2 queries. This case I need to filter the collection because the item could or could not be there and if it's there it's always only one but the other can be multiple. I want to use only one query to eager load everything. I then filter the collection in other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your database query to just return one element. If the result is always just one, there is no need to load an entire collection.

```
$item = Item::where(/*some constraints*/)->where('item_color_id', 1)->first();
if (isset($item))
    echo $item->item_brand_id;
```

Comment: No, I don't want multiple queries